# What is the right way to multiply a named vector by a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

Similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382883/what-is-the-right-way-to-multiply-data-frame-by-vector), what is the right way to multiply a named vector by a dataframe, such that each row is multiplied by corresponding element of the vector?

```
df <- data.frame(A=1:5, B=2:6)
v <- c(2, 0)
names(v) <- c("B", "A")
```

I would like the following output:

```
   A  B
1  0  4
2  0  6
3  0  8
4  0 10
5  0 12
```

None of the suggested solutions from the other question match column names with the names of the vector. For example,

```
dt <- data.table(df)
for (i in seq_along(dt))
    dt[, i := dt[[i]] * v[i], with = F]

dt
    A B
1:  2 0
2:  4 0
3:  6 0
4:  8 0
5: 10 0
```

I can do it by reordering v, but I wonder whether there's a better way to do this:

```
v <- v[colnames(df)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
r <- mapply('*', df, v[names(df)])
# or equivalently: mapply(function(x,y) x*y, df, v[names(df)])

#     A  B
#[1,] 0  4
#[2,] 0  6
#[3,] 0  8
#[4,] 0 10
#[5,] 0 12
```

`v[names(df)]` will give the vector elements in the same order as they are in `df`, so column-name-respective, so to say.

If you want to have `r` as data frame, just do `as.data.frame(r)`.

This is from `?mapply`

> mapply is a multivariate version of sapply. mapply applies FUN to the first elements of each ... argument, the second elements, the third elements, and so on. Arguments are recycled if necessary.

`FUN` is `*` in our setting.

Answer (score 3):

We can loop through the names using `lapply`, then `cbind`:

```
res <- do.call(cbind, 
               lapply(names(df), function(i){
                 df[i] * v[i]
               }))


class(res)
# [1] "data.frame"
res
#   A  B
# 1 0  4
# 2 0  6
# 3 0  8
# 4 0 10
# 5 0 12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following (transpose the data.frame, multiply by the ordered vector, and then transpose again):

```
  as.data.frame(t(t(df)*v[colnames(df)]))
```

Here are some benchmarks on a larger data frame: (`f1` is @zx8754's function and `f2` is @m0h3n's function)

```
df <- data.frame(A=1:5000, B=2:5001)
v <- c(2, 0)
names(v) <- c("B", "A")

library(microbenchmark)

f1 <- function(){
  do.call(cbind, 
          lapply(names(df), function(i){
            df[i] * v[i]
          }))
}

f2 <- function(){
  as.data.frame(mapply('*', df, v[names(df)]))
}

f3 <- function(){
  as.data.frame(t(t(df)*v[colnames(df)]))
}

microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3())

Unit: microseconds
 expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 f1()  594.394  663.9595  711.3634  690.8815  748.8425 1022.605   100  b 
 f2() 2428.762 2618.7460 2701.1528 2669.4355 2730.8070 3904.354   100   c
 f3()  251.776  361.7550  401.8032  381.8825  418.6225  793.604   100 a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more variables in the dataframe than elements in the vector you may want to use an extended version of @jav's answer:

```
library(magrittr) 
df %>% 
  select(one_of(vars)) %$% 
  as.data.frame(t(t(.)*multiplier[vars])) %>% 
  bind_cols(df %>% select(-one_of(vars)))
```

Alternatively you can use the [`map2_df`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.2/topics/map2) function from the [`purrr`](https://github.com/hadley/purrr) package to do the leg work (and I am shamelessly borrowing [@akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39802965/2114932) to my (as it turns out) [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39795136/2114932) here).

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  select(one_of(vars)) %>% 
  map2_df(multiplier[vars], ~ .x * .y)  %>%
  bind_cols(df %>% select(-one_of(vars)))
```

If you are keen on keeping the original order of the variables, just add `%>% select(one_of(names(df)))` to either one.

Performance-wise these two seem to be pretty much on par:

```
f4 <- function(){
  df %>% 
    select(one_of(vars)) %$% 
    as.data.frame(t(t(.)*multiplier[vars])) %>% 
    bind_cols(df %>% select(-one_of(vars))) 
  }

f5 <- function(){
  df %>% 
    select(one_of(vars)) %>% 
    map2_df(multiplier[vars], ~ .x * .y)  %>%
    bind_cols(df %>% select(-one_of(vars))) 
}

microbenchmark(f4(), f5())

Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 f4() 1.142170 1.178752 1.320680 1.197293 1.227915 2.858073   100
 f5() 1.155081 1.180077 1.248928 1.206396 1.227915 2.647517   100
```