# How can I manipulate dataframe columns with different values from an external vector (with dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

In R, I would like to manipulate (say multiply) data.frame columns with appropriately named values stored in a vector (or data.frame, if that's easier).

Let's say, I want to first `summarise` the variables `disp`, `hp`, and `wt` from the `mtcars` dataset.

```
vars <- c("disp", "hp", "wt")
mtcars %>% 
  summarise_at(vars, funs(sum(.))
```

(throw a `group_by(cyl)` into the mix, or use `mutate_at` if you'd like to have more rows)

Now I'd like to multiply each of the resulting columns with a particular value, given by

```
multiplier <- c("disp" = 2, "hp" = 3, "wt" = 4)
```

Is it possible to refer to these within the `summarise_at` function?

The result should look like this (and I don't want to have to refer to the variable names directly while getting there):

```
disp    hp    wt
14766.2 14082 411.808
```

UPDATE:

Maybe my MWE was too minimal. Let's say I want to do the same operation with a data.frame grouped by `cyl`

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars, sum)
```

The result should thus be:

```
    cyl   disp   hp      wt
1     4 2313.0 2727 100.572
2     6 2566.4 2568  87.280
3     8 9886.8 8787 223.956
```

UPDATE 2:

Maybe I was not explicit enough here either, but the columns in the data.frame should be multiplied by the respective values in the vector (and only those columns mentioned in the vector), so e.g. `disp` should be multiplied by 2, `hp` by 3 and `wt` by 4, all other variables (e.g. `cyl`) should remain untouched by the multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could also do this with `map` function from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
mtcars %>%
    summarise_at(vars, sum) %>%
    map2_df(multiplier, `*`)
#      disp    hp      wt
#     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 14766.2 14082 411.808
```

---

For the updated question

```
d1 <- mtcars %>% 
         group_by(cyl) %>% 
         summarise_at(vars, sum) 
d1 %>% 
   select(one_of(vars)) %>% 
   map2_df(multiplier[vars], ~ .x * .y) %>%
   bind_cols(d1 %>% select(-one_of(vars)), .) 
#    cyl   disp    hp      wt
#  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     4 2313.0  2727 100.572
#2     6 2566.4  2568  87.280
#3     8 9886.8  8787 223.956
```

---

Or we can use `gather/spread`

```
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars, sum) %>% 
    gather(var, val, -cyl) %>% 
    mutate(val = val*multiplier[match(var, names(multiplier))]) %>% 
    spread(var, val)
#     cyl   disp    hp      wt
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     4 2313.0  2727 100.572
#2     6 2566.4  2568  87.280
#3     8 9886.8  8787 223.956
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but this does not work with a `group_by(cyl)`, does it? I get "Error: `.x` (4) and `.y` (3) are different lengths"

Comment: @dapperdan  Your question was not about `group_by`

Comment: Well, maybe I wasn't explicit enough, but I did mention "(throw a group_by(cyl) into the mix, or use mutate_at if you'd like to have more rows)", didn't I?

Comment: No problem. But there is more to a question than just the code. ;-) I made it more explicit, as you can see.

Comment: :D. That's the right direction, but we are not there quite yet. Because the multiplier vector is named for a reason. If you change it's order to `multiplier <- c("wt" = 4, "disp" = 2, "hp" = 3)` your code multiplies `disp` by 4, `hp` by 2 and `wt` by 3 and that's clearly not what I want.

Comment: @dapperdan In that case just do `multiplier[vars]`

Comment: Well I'd argue that it was all there in the original question. Just not explicit enough for people who just read the code and not the prose. :P Seriously, thanks a lot for the intro to `purrr`. I also like the `tidyr`approach even though it performs slightly worse. I hope you don't mind me adding a little something to the `select` and `bind_cols` functions to make it more generally applicable?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do this in the `summarise_at` function, but this is close alternative...

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

vars <- c("disp", "hp", "wt")
multiplier <- c("disp" = 2, "hp" = 3, "wt" = 4)

mtcars %>% 
    summarise_at(vars, sum) %>% 
    do(. * multiplier) 

     disp    hp      wt
1 14766.2 14082 411.808
```

****REDUX****

Include the grouping var `cyl` in the `multiplier` and set it equal to 1. `@akrun's` `map2_df` does the real work here.

```
vars <- c("disp", "hp", "wt")
multiplier <- c("cyl" = 1, "disp" = 2, "hp" = 3, "wt" = 4)

mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars, sum) %>% 
    map2_df(multiplier, ~ .x * .y) 


    cyl   disp    hp      wt
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     4 2313.0  2727 100.572
2     6 2566.4  2568  87.280
3     8 9886.8  8787 223.956
```

Comment: Not bad, but when I have more rows (e.g. by adding add a `group_by(cyl)`) these get multiplied row-wise. And additional columns (here `cyl`) get multiplied as well. I just want to multiply the columns mentioned in the named vector with the values in that vector, so disp*2, hp*3, wt*4).

Comment: Well, I think the better alternative to adding `cyl` to `multiplier` is to use `multiplier[vars]` in the `map2_df` because it is more general. This and the rest is really @akrun's answer, so I am marking his as the answer to my question.