# tidyverse solution for multiplying columns by a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I looked for solutions here: [Multiply columns in a data frame by a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111444/multiply-columns-in-a-data-frame-by-a-vector) and here: [What is the right way to multiply data frame by vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382883/what-is-the-right-way-to-multiply-data-frame-by-vector), but it doesn't really work.

What I want to do is a more or less clean tidyverse way where I multiply columns by a vector and then add these as new columns to the existing data frame. Taking teh data example from the first link:

```
c1 <- c(1,2,3)
c2 <- c(4,5,6)
c3 <- c(7,8,9)
d1 <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3)

  c1 c2 c3
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  3  6  9

v1 <- c(1,2,3)
```

my desired result would be:

```
  c1 c2 c3 pro_c1 pro_c2 pro_c3
1  1  4  7      1      8     21
2  2  5  8      2     10     24
3  3  6  9      3     12     27
```

I tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
d1 |>
  mutate(pro = sweep(across(everything()), 2, v1, "*"))
```

But here the problem is the new columns are actually a data frame within my data frame. And I'm struggling with turning this data frame-in-data frame into regular columns. I assume, I could probably first setNames on this inner data frame and then unnest, but wondering if there's a more direct way by looping over each column with `across` and feed it with the first/second/third element of `v1`?

(I know I could probably also first create a standalone data frame with the three new multiplied columns, give them a unique name and then `bind_cols` on both, d1 and the df with the products.)

Comment: @akrun if "by row" means that I want to multiply all c1 rows with the first value of v1, then all rows of c2 with the second value of v2 and so on, then yes, by row.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR the vector is v1.

Comment: c1 is multiplied with 1. c2 is multiploed with 2. c3 is multiplied with 3. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is by row, then one option is `c_across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
new <- as_tibble(setNames(as.list(v1), names(d1)))
d1 %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(c_across(everything()) * new) %>%
  rename_with(~ str_c("pro_", .x), everything()) %>%
  bind_cols(d1, .)
```

-output

```
   1 c2 c3 pro_c1 pro_c2 pro_c3
1  1  4  7      1      8     21
2  2  5  8      2     10     24
3  3  6  9      3     12     27
```

---

Or another option is `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2_dfc(d1, v1,  `*`) %>%
   rename_with(~ str_c("pro_", .x), everything()) %>%
   bind_cols(d1, .)
```

-output

```
 c1 c2 c3 pro_c1 pro_c2 pro_c3
1  1  4  7      1      8     21
2  2  5  8      2     10     24
3  3  6  9      3     12     27
```

---

Also, with the OP' approach, it is a `data.frame` column.  It can be `unpack`ed

```
library(tidyr)
d1 |> 
    mutate(pro = sweep(cur_data(), 2, v1, `*`)) |> 
    unpack(pro, names_sep = "_")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 6
     c1    c2    c3 pro_c1 pro_c2 pro_c3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     4     7      1      8     21
2     2     5     8      2     10     24
3     3     6     9      3     12     27
```

EDIT: Based on @deschen comments with `names_sep`

Comment: Awesome, the unpack solution is great. BTW, you could simplify this a bit more by replacing the whole setNames part by unpacks `names_sep = "_"`.

Answer (score 4):

This is perhaps ridiculous, but you could use

```r
library(dplyr)

d1 %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                ~.x * v1[which(names(d1) == cur_column())],
                .names = "pro_{.col}"))
```

which returns

```r
  c1 c2 c3 pro_c1 pro_c2 pro_c3
1  1  4  7      1      8     21
2  2  5  8      2     10     24
3  3  6  9      3     12     27
```

Comment: Thank you my dear friend, I hope you are also doing great.

Comment: Interesting one.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the fun part, I trialed & errored a bit more after seeing some of your solutions. Since I started treating myself to the pain of using the base R native pipe which doesn't yet allow for passing a "." argument silently as the first argument, I had to fiddle around with it a bit more:

```
library(tidyverse)
d1 |> 
  (\(x)(bind_cols(x, x |>
                       map2_dfc(v1, `*`) |> 
                       rename_with(.cols = everything(),
                                   .fn   = ~paste0("pro_", .)))))()

  c1 c2 c3 pro_c1 pro_c2 pro_c3
1  1  4  7      1      8     21
2  2  5  8      2     10     24
3  3  6  9      3     12     27
```

---

Found an even easier solution:

```
d1 |> 
  add_column(d1 |> 
               map2_dfc(v1, `*`) |> 
               rename_with(.cols = everything(),
                           .fn   = ~paste0("pct_", .)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dplyr-ized version of the usual `apply(. , 1, fun)` paradigm:

```
d1 %>% apply(1, "*", v1) %>% t %>% cbind(d1, .)

  c1 c2 c3 c1 c2 c3
1  1  4  7  1  8 21
2  2  5  8  2 10 24
3  3  6  9  3 12 27
```

It gets a bit hackish if you want to assign column names to the matrix before binding back to the starting dataframe:

```
d1 %>% apply(1, "*", v1) %>% t %>% `colnames<-`(.,  paste0("pro_", colnames(.))) %>% cbind(d1, .)
  c1 c2 c3 pro_c1 pro_c2 pro_c3
1  1  4  7      1      8     21
2  2  5  8      2     10     24
3  3  6  9      3     12     27
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @IRTFM's solution, but does not need `apply(...)`

```
 cbind(d1, t(t(d1)*v1))

##   c1 c2 c3 c1 c2 c3
## 1  1  4  7  1  8 21
## 2  2  5  8  2 10 24
## 3  3  6  9  3 12 27
```

Or,

```
result <- cbind(d1, t(t(d1)*v1))
colnames(result) <- c(colnames(d1), paste0('pro_', colnames(d1)))
result
```

which gives the column names you want.